# D3 v4 missing node

Tags: d3.js

I'm new to D3 library (v4) and I need to build several force-direct layouts.
Reusing the code from [https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045][1] I have build a test with several rectangle nodes and with text inside. In fact there are 13 nodes with some links. However the layout only shows 12 nodes (from "Node 1" to "Node 12") although the link of "Node 0" is drawn. A look a the DOM only shows 12  and 12  while the console.log() list correctly 13 node objects and text labels. Please may somebody explain-me what is incorrect in the code below .

```
   var graph = { "nodes":
   [{"id":"Node 0","group":2},{"id":"Node 1","group":2},
   {"id":"Node 2","group":2},{"id":"Node 3","group":2},
   {"id":"Node 4","group":2},{"id":"Node 5","group":2},
   {"id":"Node 6","group":2},{"id":"Node 7","group":2},
   {"id":"Node 8","group":2},{"id":"Node 9","group":2},
   {"id":"Node 10","group":2},{"id":"Node 11","group":2},
   {"id":"Node 12","group":4}],
   "links":
   [{"source":"Node 0","target":"Node 1","value":"5"},
   {"source":"Node 1","target":"Node 5","value":"5"},
   {"source":"Node 2","target":"Node 1","value":"5"},
   {"source":"Node 3","target":"Node 2","value":"5"},
   {"source":"Node 3","target":"Node 1","value":"5"},
   {"source":"Node 3","target":"Node 5","value":"5"},
   {"source":"Node 4","target":"Node 3","value":"5"},
   {"source":"Node 4","target":"Node 8","value":"5"},
   {"source":"Node 5","target":"Node 8","value":"5"},
   {"source":"Node 6","target":"Node 9","value":"5"},
   {"source":"Node 7","target":"Node 3","value":"5"},
   {"source":"Node 8","target":"Node 10","value":"5"},
   {"source":"Node 9","target":"Node 10","value":"5"},
   {"source":"Node 9","target":"Node 7","value":"5"},
   {"source":"Node 10","target":"Node 12","value":"20"},
   {"source":"Node 11","target":"Node 7","value":"5"}]
   };

   var svg = d3.select("svg"),
        width = +svg.attr("width"),
        height = +svg.attr("height");

   var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20).domain(d3.range(1,20));;

   var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
       .force("link", d3.forceLink().id(function(d) { return d.id; }).distance(100))
       .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody())
       .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

   var link = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "links")
    .selectAll("line")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter().append("line")
    .attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return Math.sqrt(d.value); });

   var nodes = svg.selectAll("g")      
     .data(graph.nodes)
     .enter()
     .append("g");

   nodes.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "nodes")
    .attr("width", 70)
    .attr("height", 20)
    .attr("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
    .call(d3.drag()
      .on("start", dragstarted)
      .on("drag", dragged)
      .on("end", dragended));

   nodes.append("text")
    .attr("class", "labels")
    .attr("dy", "1.5em")
    .attr("dx", "1.5em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "start")
    .text(function(d) { return d.id; });

   nodes.selectAll('rect')
     .attr("width", function(d) {return this.parentNode.getBBox().width+10;})

   simulation
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .on("tick", ticked);

   simulation.force("link")
   .links(graph.links);

   function ticked() {
     link
    .attr("x1", function(d) { return d.source.x; })
    .attr("y1", function(d) { return d.source.y; })
    .attr("x2", function(d) { return d.target.x; })
    .attr("y2", function(d) { return d.target.y; });

    nodes.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
   }

   function dragstarted(d) {
     if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
   }

   function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
   }

   function dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
     d.fx = null;
     d.fy = null;  
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line:

```
var nodes = svg.selectAll("g")      
   .data(graph.nodes)
   .enter()
   .append("g");
```

You are "selecting all groups". However, when it runs, you already have one `<g>` element in the DOM (look at `var link`). Because of that, your first datum will be bound to that existing `<g>` and your enter selection will have one element less.

Solution: select something that **does not exist**:

```
var nodes = svg.selectAll("foo")      
   .data(graph.nodes)
   .enter()
   .append("g");
```